# How is SceneBuilder8 adding the APPLY button to WizardPane?

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm working on building a wizard using ControlsFX 8.40.10 (latest release at this time).  SceneBuilder8 was downloaded from Gluon and includes the ControlsFX library.  When I select a WizardPane in SceneBuilder, I can open the Properties tab on the right and under "Button Types" I can add the "APPLY" button.

(See the image at [SceneBuilder8 UI view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbHwu.png))

How do I handle events triggered by this button?  I added a click handler to the FXML document by using the Code panel in SceneBuilder, but my handler is never invoked; it seems the onClick applies to the WizardPane as a whole, not the button.  When the button is pressed, however, it triggers the return of **wiz.showAndWait()**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import org.controlsfx.dialog.*?>

<WizardPane headerText="Start a Server Dialog (page 4)" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" onMouseClicked="#applyButton" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Sas_p4">
   <content>
      <VBox spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Gathering information..." />
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true">
               <content>
                  <ListView fx:id="messages" />
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </content>
   <buttonTypes>
      <ButtonType fx:constant="APPLY" />
   </buttonTypes>
</WizardPane>
```

I'd like to add code to the handler so that I can validate data up to that point in the wizard, then move them to the next WizardPane.  But how??

Comment: Showing us some code/fxml would definitely be a lot of help.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it might be something truly stupid on my part and someone would point it out and I'd be appropriately humiliated.  I guess not. ;)  I have edited the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I just wasn't reading the JavaDoc properly.

SceneBuilder8 allows the specification of optional buttons to add to the button bar at the bottom of each wizard page (ie. WizardPane).  I chose APPLY so a button with that label appeared.  But handling button presses isn't done by the WizardPane, it's done by the Wizard, which SceneBuilder can't help with.

After loading the FXML documents and creating WizardPane objects and adding them to the Wizard, I can then register button event handlers.  I search the WizardPane using **lookupButton()** and specifying which button I want, such as **ButtonType.APPLY** in this case.

The return value is a **Button**.  This means **addEventFilter()** can be called on it to register a handler for the **ActionEvent.ACTION** event.  The APPLY button has characteristics that cause the dialog to be closed by default (see the **ButtonType** documentation), but as long as the **consume()** method of the event object is invoked, the default action will NOT happen.  This is what I wanted to accomplish.

I now have a different problem.  I want each WizardPane to be self-contained, so I need the button handling on the pane, not on the dialog.  But that's a topic for another question...